# Cosmos DB request charge (RU) changes depending on allocated throughput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the Cosmos DB Data Explorer in the Azure portal to experiment with query performance, and have encountered a (reproducible) behavior I don't understand.

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT c.displayname FROM c WHERE
STARTSWITH(c.displayname,'Large object',true)
ORDER BY c.completedtime DESC
```

The collection has a single physical partition, uses the document ID as partition key, contains about 300k objects, and has a size of 2 GB (including 600 MB indexes). The query above matches 1277 documents that are disproportionately large (about 150 kB), but the projected propery `displayname` is short.

Allocating **400 RU/s** throughput and executing this query in the Data Explorer (which has a fixed page size of 100) consumes **268,860 RUs and takes about half an hour**. (More stats: retrieved document count 129073; retrieved document size 69091206095 B = **69 GB** (!); output document count 101; output document size 21014 B, index hit document count 129073; index lookup time 1689 ms; document load time 116399 ms; query engine execution time 479 ms; round trips 1.)

However, at **2000 RU/s**, the query only consumes **5806 RUs and takes about 2 s** to finish. (More stats: retrieved document count 2717 ; retrieved document size 1493282347 B = 1.4 GB; output document count 170; output document size 27457 B, index hit document count 2717; index lookup time 33 ms; document load time 2601 ms; query engine execution time 35 ms; round trips 1.)

1. Why is the RU charge of certain queries almost 50 times higher with 400 RU/s throughput as compared to 2000 RU/s?
2. How can the retrieved document size be 69 GB if the entire collection only takes up 1.6 GB storage?

Comment: Not sure about the RU differences. It's making a "full table scan", the partition key is not specified also if `c. displayname` has an index, with the `STARTSWITH` it may not be using it. From cosmos side did you notice any 429 - Request rate too large?

Comment: What kind of stats do you see if you remove the `ORDER BY` (but project `c.completedtime` so it can be ordered in the application)?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's not a problem without the `ORDER BY`. But my question is not about how to optimize this particular query, but why certain queries seem to result in a messed up execution plan (only) when the little throughput is allocated.